# C++ pointer to functions, Beginner Question

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I want to ask about pointer in C++

I have some simple code:

```
int add(int a, int b){
 return a+b;
}

int runner(int x,int y, int (*functocall)(int, int)){
 return (*functocall)(x,y);
}
```

now, suppose I call those functions using this way :

```
cout<<runner(2,5,&add);
```

or maybe

```
cout<<runner(2,5,add);
```

is there any difference? because when I tried, the result is the same and with no error.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

Function will be implicitly casted to a pointer according to C++ Standard (4.3/1). There is no difference. However this conversion never applies to nonstatic member functions. For them you should explicitly write `&`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. For consistency with other ways of getting a pointer you can use `&`, but the name by itself would have no other meaning so it is assumed to mean "get the address".

It's very similar to array variable names acting as the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

No, in this particular case there is no difference. Either one gives you the address of the function.

Note, however, that in C++, getting a pointer to a *member* function requires that you use the '&' operator.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you can have references to functions

```
int runner(int x,int y, int (&functocall)(int, int)){
 return functocall(x,y);
}
```

Now calling it with `&add` won't work anymore because you try to bind a function reference to a pointer instead of to a function. Sometimes this shines through when using templates

```
template<typename T>
int runner(int x,int y, T &functocall, T otherfunc){
 return functocall(x,y) + otherfunc(y, x);
}
```

Now calling it with `runner(10, 20, add, add)` will fail because `T` is tried to be deduced to both a function pointer and a function type (no decay to a pointer is done when passing to a reference parameter!).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the second call automatically resolves to the first call in the compiler...

Comment: no, I mean that the compiler resolves either call to a function pointer, and it's really a matter of syntactic preference.

Answer (score 0):

it is because there is no such object (in terms of expressions) as **function**, there are only **pointers to functions**. When you want to pass function to your function the only thing you can actually pass is pointer, so compiler does this cast for you

Comment: There are objects called functions (in terms of expressions): `add` is such an object, its type is `int (int, int)`. They do implicitly decay to pointers to themselves in many contexts though.

Comment: please show example where function and pointer to function as expression term really differ

Comment: Yes, functions aren't objects, but they are functions (surprise xD). For example `void f() { } void (&fr)() = f;` works because f is an expression of function type and you bind the reference to it, while `void (&fr)() = &f;` does not work because `&f` is an expression of pointer type. Another example - try to do `sizeof(f)` and notice that it fails, because functions don't have a size. Like @avakar says, the type of f in here is `void()`, and the one of add is `int(int, int)`